# How to you serve content of one web server to another?

Tags: web-server, reverse-proxy

I am building an application where a blog will be hosted on a server controled by myself (on apache) and served to a clients website (could be on any webserver). I will have multiple clients accessing a blog that I will set up for them on another server, for example:

clientsite.com/blog should load content from mywebsite.com/client1.

What is the best way to do this? I think that reverse proxies could be a possibility, but as I would not be in control of the clients servers, how could I configure the client servers to do what I want?

The goal of this is to be able to set up a blog for clients that I can manage for them and looks like it is part of their own website for maximum SEO value.

Comment: Why not to add Cname in DNS for your client subdomian pointing to your server.

Comment: I need to use subfolders in order to pass as much SEO value as possible to clientsite.com. If I used subdomain.clientsite.com then clientsite.com would not get the full benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redirect/Rewrite feature which is available in various HTTP servers.
E.g. in case of Apache it would be:

```
RewriteRule   ^/blog  http://mywebsite.com/client1  [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The DNS CNAME seems to be a very good solution - one used by many for the same problem you face.

Can you please explain why you think this might not give you the SEO benefit you think?  URLs are only one facet of SEO.  Meta-data (not simply the keywords tag) embedded in the page along with good titles is extremely important.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812

Comment: From what I understand, subdomains are best used when you want that subdomain to be judged on its own merit. In my case I want the entire client website to benefit, not just the subdomain. http://www.seomoz.org/q/subdirectory-vs-subdomain